# ggplot2 separating legend by shape

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
# Data:  
zz <- "Small Large  Lat  Long 
1       51   2       11    10 
2       49   0       12    11  
3       77   7       13    13  
4       46   5       12    15     
5       32   6       13    14      
6       54   3       15    17
7       68   0       14    10
8       39   5       12    13"

Data <- as.data.frame(read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE))
```

I have a continuous variable, a ratio (small/large), I am successfully plotting.

Although, some 0s exist within the 'large' variable. When this occurs, I just want to plot the 'small' number as a ratio is impossible. To do this I have the following:

```
ratio.both <- Data %>% 
  filter(Large > 0) %>% 
  mutate(Ratio = Small/Large)

only.sml<- Data %>% 
  filter(Large < 1)
```

I then plot both on the same graph (by lat long data):

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = ratio.both,
             aes(x = Long,
                 y = Lat,
                 size = Ratio),
             stroke = 0,
             colour = '#3B3B3B',
             shape=16) +
  #
  geom_point(data = only.sml,
             aes(x = Long,
                 y = Lat,
                 size = Small,
                 shape=1),
             stroke = 1,
             shape=1)
```

**Notice the difference in shape.** This plots the following

[image: not the nicest graph but demonstrates example]
*not the nicest graph but demonstrates example*

The difference between those which are a ratio (filled) and those which are just the small value is clear on the map but difficult in the legend.

I want the following in the legend:

```
   #Title
   Size = both.ratio$Ratio,
   Shape/fill = Ratio or small value #whichever is easier
```

Comment: Absolutely, please provide sample data. (I suggest that reshaping the data before plotting might be useful, such as `Size = ifelse(Large>0, Size, somethingelse)`.)

Comment: Sure. Will do so and update now. 

Yes I thought reshape and then fill based on presence/absence (e.g. if large > 0 colour = black, else = white). Thank you for your comment

Comment: please find edits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is much easier to use variables in the table to contrast the data using the built in aesthetics mapping, instead of creating separate geoms for the small and large data. You can for example create a new variable that checks whether that datapoint belongs to the large or small "type". You can then map shape, color, size or whatever you want in aesthetics and optionally add scales for these manually (if you want).

```
Data %>% 
  mutate(is_large = ifelse(Large > 0, "Ratio", "Small"),

         size = ifelse(is_large == "Large", Small/Large, Small)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Long, Lat, 
             size = size, 
             shape = is_large)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c("Ratio" = 16, "Small" = 1), 
                     name = "Size") +
  scale_size_continuous(name = "Ratio/small value")
```

[image]

Or if you want to contrast by point color:

```
Data %>% 
  mutate(is_large = ifelse(Large > 0, "Ratio", "Small"),

         size = ifelse(is_large == "Large", Small/Large, Small)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Long, Lat, 
             size = size, 
             color = is_large)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Ratio" = "blue", "Small" = "red"), 
                     name = "Size") +
  scale_size_continuous(name = "Ratio/small value")
```

[image]